# If a country wants to build nuclear weapons, why would they enrich uranium instead of turning uranium to plutonium?

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

Firstly, I have to say that I'm bad at physics. So, please correct me if I say something wrong.

I have read that natural uranium contains 99.28% of U-238 and only 0.72% of U-235 which is the fissionable isotope of uranium. If a country wants to build nukes, they should first mine uraninite, extract uranium or UF6 and then separate the 238 isotope from the 235 isotope using a separation method like gaseous diffusion or feeding it into centrifuges. Once they have five to ten kilograms of HEU (+95%), then they can build an atomic bomb.

Now, today I realized that you can turn U-238 into plutonium-239 by adding one neutron to U-238. I read that the decay process takes 2 days to complete. If that is true, then it seems a lot easier than building an A-bomb using HEU. So, why is uranium enrichment a big deal and a serious reason for proliferation concerns if even natural uranium can be extremely dangerous and there are other ways of building the A-bomb without uranium enrichment?

Comment: That is a very broad question. You really read up on the complexities/advantages/disadvantages of both processes. It's difficult to summarize it here.

Comment: @Gert Could you list a few of these advantages/disadvantages? That's all I'm looking for really. It doesn't have to be a complete answer that makes me a nuclear physicist. Just some points and references for further reading would be enough for me.

Comment: One needs a nuclear reactor. The other doesn't.

Comment: @JonCuster So, am I right to assume that if a country has nuclear reactors, then it can turn U-238 into Pu-239? Can't they just bombard U-238 with a ray of neutrons hoping that some of the uranium atoms would absorb the neutrons and then use chemical reactions to separate uranium from plutonium?

Comment: Where do you get a ray of neutrons with enough neutrons to convert enough U to Pu except from a reactor?

Comment: @JonCuster I don't know. I'm not an expert. But I watched a YouTube video about a Polonium-Beryllium neutron source [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uQ8vwevCq8Q). Can't it be used to create a ray of neutrons?

Comment: For one brief moment in time you get a few neutrons by mixing Po and Be.

Comment: @JonCuster So, the challenge is about having a powerful source of neutrons which is impossible without having a working nuclear reactor. Do I understand you correctly? Even if so, can't they just feed small amounts of LEU to their nuclear reactor to have a source for neutron emission?

Comment: @stressedout Creating a beam of neutrons is easy. Creating a beam of *enough* neutrons to produce any significant amount of nuclear material is, practically speaking, impossible. Neutron beams in production produce a very small number of neutrons, perhaps $10^{12}$ per second, while a kilogram of plutonium requires more like $10^{27}$ neutrons to produce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few points to which I invite the experts to add.

Breeding plutonium out of uranium requires you to build a breeder reactor, which is a huge undertaking, and the chemical separation process for extracting the plutonium must be designed for remote operation because the radiation levels present during the process are lethal to humans. However, you can make fissionable fuel out of U238 which enhances the fissionable yield of the ore.

A plutonium bomb is far more difficult to engineer because the gun assembly process for building a critical mass cannot be used.

Building a uranium enrichment process requires centrifuge technology which is less technically challenging than a breeder and remote separation, but the yield of fissionable uranium is fixed at the U235/U238 ratio present in the ore.

A uranium bomb is easier to engineer because the gun method (which is relatively straightforward) can be used.

Comment: The Manhattan Project did not use (gas) centrifuge technology to enrich the uranium. Other attempted proliferators, notably Iraq, have also at least started to go down the Calutron path used in the 1940s.

Comment: I know manhattan used gas diffusion and the calutron, but the calutron was notoriously inefficient. I do not know why Iraq would have been interested in it, do you by chance? the centrifuges seem to be today's method of choice...

Comment: The Manhattan project folks looked into gas diffusion, but needed better alloys to deal with UF6. They did use liquid diffusion processes during the war, and those helped get the feedstock to the Calutrons up so that fewer passes were needed. Centrifuges today remain higher tech, and more obvious to non-proliferation monitoring. Calutrons are pretty bulletproof in concept. Start somewhere like https://fas.org/nuke/guide/iraq/facility/tarmiya.htm to get an idea of what Iraq was up to.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the uranium needs to be enriched to turn it into reactor grade uranium, because reactors are necessary to create plutonium. In order to build a bomb with it, the U needs to be further enriched to turn it into weapons grade uranium. Uranium bombs are easier to build, as a critical mass is achieved by using a uranium gun to bring two pieces of enriched uranium suddenly together. Making a plutonium bomb is much harder, as the critical mass is created by using HE to compress the Pu-239, which is quite a tricky thing to do, as the explosive compression has to be exactly equal all around the plutonium sphere. Another fly in the ointment is that the Pu-239 tends to be contaminated by small amounts of Pu-240. The bomb dropped on Hiroshima was a uranium bomb, while the one dropped on Nagasaki was a plutonium bomb. The Hiroshima bomb was slightly more powerful.

Comment: Heavy water reactors can use natural uranium as fuel, and reactors using natural uranium have been used to produce plutonium in the past. e.g. India's [CIRUS reactor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIRUS_reactor).